# Flex Mobile in Android Quick Start

Tags: android, apache-flex

I would like to learn how to use flex to write a mobile apps.
I found some tutorial like this http://coenraets.org/flexandroid90/FlexAndroid90Minutes.pdf
or this http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flex/articles/twitter-trends.html
Although they have good example to demo, it is hard to learn since I have no experience of writing flex.
Is there any tutorial talking about the basic things of flex i.e. syntax, structure??

Answer (score 1):

**know about Adobe Air ::**

- What is Adobe AIR?

The Adobe® AIR® runtime enables developers to deploy standalone applications built with HTML, JavaScript, ActionScript®, Flex, Adobe Flash® Professional, and Adobe Flash Builder® across platforms and devices — including Android™, BlackBerry®, iOS devices, personal computers, and televisions.

[**More info......**](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html)